# image thumb list with opacity changes and add class/remove class on click

Tags: javascript, html, thumbnails, opacity

I got the script from another post on here, but for some reason it isn't working quite correctly on my implementation of it. Everything works fine except for stripping of the "selected" class, therefore the thumbnails all stay highlighted after being clicked. Easiest way is to show in context:

http://www.studioimbrue.com/beta

I changed it around a bit trying to figure out the problem but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On click, get all other thumbnails of group (by parent element fo example) and remove "selected" classname

Comment: I tried a few things, but my javascript is definitely lacking to say the least... mind giving me a hand with that one? haha

Thanks for your help though